# Is it possible to bind and unbind an element on button click? - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-model

I created a display text and an input field and bind them together with ng-model as follow.

HTML

```
  <div ng-app ng-controller="test">
    <div ng-bind="content"></div>
    <input id="txtElem" type="text" ng-model="content">
        <button ng-click="stopBinding()"> Unbind</button>
        <button ng-click="binding()"> Bind </button>
  </div>
```

JS

```
function test( $scope ) {
    $scope.content = 'Welcome';

     $scope.binding = function() {
       angular.element(document.getElementById('txtElem')).bind();
    };

    $scope.stopBinding = function() {
       angular.element(document.getElementById('txtElem')).unbind();
    };
};
```

Display

[image]

I found this(http://jsfiddle.net/jexgF/) for unbind method, but don't know how to bind it again, if "Bind" button is clicked. Anyone could help?

Apart from bind and unbind between elements of `<div>` and `<input>`, anyone know how to bind and unbind two `<input>` fields?

Comment: Why do you want to bind and unbind?

Comment: In my application, I created a preview and a textarea for entering the source code. Unbind is used during the time entering the codes to prevent injection of any other codes from preview to textarea. "Bind" is used only when preview. This is because my preview has build-in auto formatting functionality.  @DavidGrinberg, do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure where the `test()` function in your example resides, but it is not a good idea - an anti-pattern, in fact - to manipulate the DOM in the controller.

The proper way is to create a variable, separate from the input variable `content`, represents the preview part.

You could do this simply in the View; if this logic, in your opinion, is a View-only logic. `lastBound` represents the last bound value of `content`:

```
<div ng-init="binding = true">
   <input ng-model="content">
   <button ng-click="binding = false">Unbind</button>
   <button ng-click="binding = true">Bind</button>

   <div ng-bind="lastBound = (binding && content) || lastBound"></div>
</div>
```

(the use of `ng-init` here is just for illustration purposes - you should set `binding` in the controller).

**EDIT:**

If the intent is to bind to another `ng-model`, then the solution is different, but not dissimilar. You still need to use 2 variables:

```
<input ng-model="content" ng-change="preview = (binding && content) || preview">
<input ng-model="preview" ng-change="content = (binding && preview) || content">
```

Comment: Hi, @New Dev, thanks for your answering. What If I want to bind and unbind between two input fields? I tried change your code "<div ng-bind="lastBound = (binding && content) || lastBound"></div>" to "<input ng-model="lastBound = (binding && content) || lastBound"></input>" , it throw the error "Expression 'lastBound = (binding && content) || lastBound' is non-assignable." Do you have any idea?